# CakePHP: How to use a AwesomeFont icon in submit()?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'd like to use an [Font Awesome icon](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) in a submit button. I tried:

```
<?= $this->Form->submit('<i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i>', ['escape' => false]) ?>
```

But it doesn't work. How to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the code shown in the question you will end up with an HTML like this:

```
<div class="submit">
   <input type="submit" value="<i class=" fa="" fa-save="" fa-2x"="">
</div>
```

This is not something you are looking for, so try using `button` instead of `submit`:

```
<?= $this->Form->button('<i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i>',
 ['escape' => false,'type' => 'submit']) ?>
```

See here : [submit Vs button cakephp3, form helper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-buttons-and-submit-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes 4 years later, but to use font awesome, or any icon syntax for the cake form submit helper, use the following syntax:

```
$caption = "<i class='fa fa-cloud-upload fa-2x'></i>" //defines the icon
$options = ['escape'=>true]; //defines the submit button options

echo $this->Form->button($caption,$options);
```